# Software, how to extract videos of .bin files?

Tags: binary-files, combine

i downloaded a set of vídeos of concerts of old groups, it is a zip file that have inside 14 bin files. I no have idea how to extract them, or join to later extract or mount.
I tried making manually cue files, open with 7-zip, Izarc, mount with daemon tools.....but nothing work... :(

If any knows something that can help, will be great!

Thank you very much

Comment: Will the bin files play in VLC? Is each bin file on single video? A bin/cue combination is usually one binary file containing all the data for a disk, and the cue describes how to cut the bin up. Bin just means binary, so unless those bin files are binary disk images, the cue file does nothing. They are likely raw video files, so try VLC as a first option.

Comment: and if they are not playable video, then maybe opening one in a hex editor might give some clues. the first several bytes of binary files often have some sort of flag or descriptor one might use to track down the file type.

Comment: if they are segments of a split file, in windows, you can use the cmd prompt to concatenate: use "copy" with the binary mode switch "/b" { `copy /b part1.ext + part2.ext combined_file.ext` }

Comment: I will try with vlc, i only think they can be disk images lol, didn´t know that.

Comment: If i open it with Hex editor, wich offset i need to search?

Comment: The names are correlative, example: data-a.bin, data-b.bin, data-c.bin to data-z.bin, just 2 files in mid are not correlative: (data-en.bin) and (data-ru.bin)